# Visual Studio Code doesn't recognize my anaconda packages and modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, package

I'm new to Machine Learning and im trying to get used to VS Code, so I tried to use it but quickly ran into some problems (not knowing how to run python on the terminal, using the conda environment, etc). The main problem was that the packages that i have with anaconda didn't work in VS Code.

I've tried everything but I'm unable to get it running in the terminal. I'll explain myself with this example.

Example code:

```
#Not my actual code, but it's an example
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x))
plt.show()
```

When i run it,
[this shows up in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEdpL.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/arman/Desktop/Untitled-1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\arman\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\arman\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

###NOTE: this part 'DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.' basically means that it didnt find the module, sorry for the spanish.
```

, even though I'm in a conda environment. And that happens with every single package that comes with conda.

**What can I do to make it work and why is that happening?**

Comment: A few things: 1) Ensure that the Python extension is installed [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python); and 2) Press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type in `Python: Select Interpreter`. Clicking that would then list all of the available Python installations you have, including the conda one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Open VSCode from conda
2. Press Ctrl+Shift+P
3. Type Python: Select Interpreter
4. Select your conda virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot it looks like your conda environment was not activated in the terminal. If you make sure that occurs then conda can find things that you installed.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to run VS Code from Anaconda Prompt using 'code' command

Comment: This may not solve their problem. Can you please provide more steps on how the user could achieve this. I am running fine without using anaconda prompt just by launching vscode. What is the reason to prefer the anaconda prompt. Please elaborate.